# MySQL regexp does not detect equals sign

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I got a mysql database that I am trying to find some urls using REGEXP.

However, my regex does not seem to work, right at the equals sign.

An example field would be:

> POST /4jEFhi.php?p=o2k8q6j5dm9pau HTTP/1.1 ~~ Host: example.com
>   ~~ User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1;
>   Trident/4.0)

MY initial regex looks like this:

> ^POST /(?![a-z_]{6})[A-Za-z0-9_]{6}.php\?[a-z]=[a-z0-9]{10,}

However, in mysql workbench and or phpmyadmin, I face the same problems.

First, this piece:

> (?![a-z_]{6})

Does not work in MySQL, I get the following error:

Error Code: 1139. Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

If I remove it, I seem to be good to continue with

> ^POST /[A-Za-z0-9_]{6}.php\?[a-z]=[a-z0-9]{10,}

However,The detection seems to stop at the = (equals-sign)

This works, but not as precise:

> ^POST /(?![a-z_]{6})[A-Za-z0-9_]{6}.php\?[a-z]

Any help correcting this is appreciated, because my googling skills have hit the wall.

Comment: What are you expecting `(?!...)` to do?  Is is supported in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```sql
SET @`URL`    := 'POST /4jEFhi.php?p=o2k8q6j5dm9pau HTTP/1.1 ~~ Host: example.com ~~ User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)',
    @`REGEXP` := '^POST /[A-Za-z0-9_]{6}\\.php\\?[a-z]\\=[a-z0-9]{10,}';

SELECT @`URL` REGEXP BINARY @`REGEXP`;
```

Comment: thank you. This worked, not certain I understand why \\ would work, but it is.

Comment: @user3202532: `To use a literal instance of a special character in a regular expression, precede it by two backslash (\) characters. The MySQL parser interprets one of the backslashes, and the regular expression library interprets the other.`. See [12.5.2 Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html).